# How do I get a setInterval function to terminate after another function finishes off reading every letter of the input?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

```
<html>
<head>
<script defer>
 let start;
 let num = 0;
 let btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
 btn.onclick = timer;

 function timer() {
  if (start === undefined) {
  start = setInterval(count, 1000);
  }

}

clearInterval(start)

function count () {
  let input = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  let currentLet = input.charAt(num);
  if (currentLet !== '') 
  document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = 'Your letters are: ' + currentLet;

  else {
     document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = 'Your letters are: done' 
  }
   num++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>        
   <h2>Programming Question 1</h2>
   <input type="text" id="input1"><button id="btn1">Press to start</button>
   <p id="output1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a program where you enter text into the text box and then, when you click a button, it will show one letter per second until all the letters have been outputed. However, I need the setInterval function to terminate after the output says "done". How do I do that? I know clearInterval is used, but I can't figure out how to execute it automatically after it reaches 'done'. I created 'start' in order to make sure the interval function doesn't execute multiple times if you click on the button more than once before it finishes reading out all the letters of the current input. I also want the interval to start counting again if I press the button again or enter a new input value

Comment: `clearInterval(start)` is the correct way to do it, though you want to call that when you've reached the last letter or if `start` is already defined inside your `timer()` function (and then unset `start` so you can start it again when you click the button again). I'm not sure why you call `clearInterval(start)` after the definition of your `timer()` method. That doesn't do anything there since `start` isn't defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is in the num variable, you must reset the `num` variable of every click of the button.

```js
function timer() {
   if () {
      num = 0
   }
}
```

You can use `clearInterval` after the `done` log

```js
if (currentLet !== '') 
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = 'Your letters are: ' + currentLet;
else {
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = 'Your letters are: done' 
    clearInterval(start)
}
```

And last, you can't control the `interval` with `undefined` because you are declaring an interval the first time and it will never `undefined`. You must use another variable like `flag`

Full code;

```js
let start;
let num = 0;
let flag;
let btn = document.getElementById('btn1');

btn.onclick = timer;

function timer() {
  if (!flag) {
    flag = true;
    start = setInterval(count, 1000);
    num = 0
  }
}

function count() {
  let input = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  let currentLet = input.charAt(num);

  if (currentLet !== '')
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = 'Your letters are: ' + currentLet;
  else {
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = 'Your letters are: done'
    clearInterval(start)
    flag = false
  }
  num++;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>Programming Question 1</h2>
  <input type="text" id="input1"><button id="btn1">Press to start</button>
  <p id="output1"></p>
</body>

</html>
```